# If A and B are non-singular and n-square matrices. Show that $(I+BA)^{-1}=I-(((B^{-1})+A)^{-1})A$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

A and B are non-singular n-square matrices. Show that

$(I+BA)^{-1}=I-(((B^{-1})+A)^{-1})A$

Comment: If you need help with typesetting math, please see [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020).

Comment: What effort have you made so far?

Comment: Thanks @ J. W. Tanner and  Lee David Chung Lin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that $(I+BA)^{-1}$ exists,

$$\begin{align}I-((B^{-1}+A)^{-1})A&=I-([B^{-1}(I+BA)]^{-1})A\\&=I-(I+BA)^{-1}BA\\&=I-(I+BA)^{-1}(I+BA-I)\\&=I-(I+BA)^{-1}(I+BA)+(I+BA)^{-1}\\&=I-I+(I+BA)^{-1}\\&=(I+BA)^{-1}\end{align}$$

Comment: thanks @ logarithm but it should be correct as this                                        
Assuming that $(I+BA)^{-1}$ exists,

$$\begin{align}I-((B^{-1}+A)^{-1})A&=I-([B^{-1}(I+BA)]^{-1})A\\&=I-(I+BA)^{-1}BA\\&=I-(I+BA)^{-1}(I+BA-I)\\&=I-(I+BA)^{-1}(I+BA)+(I+BA)^{-1}\\&=I-I+(I+BA)^{-1}\\&=(I+BA)^{-1}\end{align}$$

Comment: $$\begin{align}I-((B^{-1}+A)^{-1})A&=I-([B^{-1}(I+BA)]^{-1})A\\&=**I-(I+BA)^{-1}BA**\\&=I-(I+BA)^{-1}(I+BA-I)\\&=I-(I+BA)^{-1}(I+BA)+(I+BA)\\&=I-I+(I+BA)^{-1}\\&=(I+BA)^{-1}\end{align}$$   in the bold row how can you interchange **I-B(I+BA)^{-1}A** into **I-(I+BA)^{-1}BA** 

Comment: @AnupaKulathunga There is no interchange. The $B^{-1}$ is inside the brackets that is raised to the $-1$. If $C=(I+BA)$, then what is happening is $[B^{-1}C]^{-1}=C^{-1}(B^{-1})^{-1}=C^{-1}B$.

Comment: thank you very much got it

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.  Substitute $C=B^{-1}+A$ and simplify
$$(I+AB)(I-(B^{-1}+A)^{-1}A)\ .$$

**Note** that your claim is not quite true: if $A=-B^{-1}$ then $I+AB=0$ and this certainly has no inverse.

Comment: +1 for that great catch at the end.

Answer (score 0):

As a hint, the statement is equivalent to:

$$(I+BA)[I-((B^{-1}+A)^{-1})A]=I$$

Can you check if that is a true statement?

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively:
$$1-\frac1{\frac1b+a}\cdot a=1-\frac{b}{1+ba}\cdot a=\frac{1+ba-ba}{1+ba}=\frac1{1+ba}.$$